# Multiple Import and Export of Images

Tags: export, import, image

I wrote a program that imports an image and creates three new images, for example "black and white" or "grey scaled".

My problem is that i work with around 200 images and it takes a long time to import the images manually, and then to save the three created images manually.

Is it possible to create a loop that imports the images and exports the three new images with a changed name to a specific folder?

For example: I import the image "holiday" from the folder "Unchanged" and export "holiday_BlackWhite" or "holiday_greyscaled" to the folder "Changed".

Comment: Related post see - http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43709/import-a-large-no-of-image-from-a-folder-together-to-mathematica-and-assign-a-v

Comment: I strongly suspect that [ImageFileApply](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFileApply.html) and [ImageFileFilter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFileFilter.html) might be useful functions to investigate.

Comment: `ImageFileApply` (filter makes little sense here) turned out to be no faster than `ParallelDo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let your images lie in `/pathtoimages/unchanged/`.

Create the folder `/pathtoimages/changed/`

```
SetDirectory["/pathtoimages/unchanged/"];
names = FileBaseName /@ FileNames["*.png"];
```

I'm using the extension `png` in my example, as I have a bunch of `png` images somewhere on my machine. If you have photos, they're most likely with the extension `jpg` - adjust accordingly.

```
Do[im = Import[name <> ".png"]; 
 Export["../changed/" <> name <> "_blackwhite.png", Binarize[im]];
 Export["../changed/" <> name <> "_grayscale.png", ColorConvert[im, "Grayscale"]];
 , {name, names}]
```

It's quite slow - took about 30 seconds for 11 files with a total size of 3MB

Comment: @Karsten7. To be honest, I have no experience with the `Parallel*` functions.I guess a speed-up is possible, unless some collisions with the repeated assignment happen.

Comment: @Karsten7. unfortunately, I'm not at the same machine I was at at the time of writing the answer.

Comment: @ LLlAMnYP. Thank you for your quick answer. To be honest, my programm a lot more complex and i used the example "holiday" just to show what kind of problem exists. But your answer gave me the right thought-provoking impulse. Thanks

Comment: @Karsten7. (though the comments have now been deleted), yes, `ParallelDo` gave a 2x speed-up.