# What's the most efficient way to batch-import, batch-process and batch-export images?

Tags: performance-tuning, export, image-processing, import

I am trying to process hundreds of images in the same way and export them automatically one by one. Right now, I only have the image processing code for one image, and I want to learn what is the most efficient way to repeat the procedure for the rest of the hundreds of images.

My code for one image is:

```
Export["C:\\Users\\ProcessedImage1.tiff",ColorNegate[ImageFilter[Max,ColorSeparate[ImageApply[{Sin[Pi#*4],Sin[Pi#],Sin[Pi#*3]}&,Import["C:\\Users\\Image1.tiff"]],"L"],1]]//Colorize]
```

Right now, I can import several the images (very large file size) to a `Table` and export them one by one again using `Table`. However, it is very slow. How do I import one image, process it, export it then delete it from *Mathematica*'s memory and move on to the next image? I am thinking `For` loop, `Table`, or `Map`, but I am not familiar with the language yet. In other words, how do I import `"ImageX.tiff"`, where X is the number in my file name, then process it and export to `"ProcessedImageX.tiff"`?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on `Table` and `TemplateApply`? In particular I think you'll want to use `Table[expr,{i,number_of_images}]` and `TemplateApply["C:\\...Image``",i]` inside `expr`.

Comment: Have you tried `ImageFileApply` and `ImageFileFilter`?

Comment: Also, `Parallelize` can be helpful here.

Comment: I usually use some variant of `Monitor[Do[processImage[file], {file, FileNames[folder]}], file]`. Where `processImage` is the function that does the actual processing. The `Monitor` is just so I can see some progress

Comment: Hi nikie, when I use Monitor[Do[processImage[file], {file, FileNames[folder]}], file], according to your suggestion, the error message is  "C:\.." not an array or an image. So instead of using FileNames[folder], I tried using Import[folder] to import my images. However, my processImage function does not work even though I got the images to show.. I just want to use a simple StandardDeviationFilter to filter all the images in this folder. Any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Actually I found how to do it in this link: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97516/multiple-import-and-export-of-images?rq=1